# Can xrandr/autorandr distinguish different monitor models connected to the same output?

Tags: nvidia, manjaro, multi-monitor, xrandr, monitors

I have a laptop with which I connect to a monitor at home and at work. In both cases I use the same HDMI out for connecting to the monitor. The one at the lab is 1440p/60hz and the one at home is 1080p/120hz when overclocked (not really, I just use a HDMI 1.4 input instead of DVI dual link).

Is there any way for xrandr to detect whether a different monitor model is connected and e.g. disable precautions for the nvidia driver as [outlined here](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Guide-to-Nvidia-monitor-overclocking-on-Linux)? Can I adjust that automatically through scripting/[autorandr](https://github.com/phillipberndt/autorandr), or would I need to see myself which one is connected and call the script accordingly?